# Custom Activity - What REQUEST_URL should be used?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest, journeybuilder

I have a custom activity where I get an error message while running a Journey.

Using **[this](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/http-request)** github library for my custom activity, I cannot get the execute function to run due to "mctype undefined" in routes/activity.js (row 182) `var mctype = isMC_API(options.url);` which leads back to a faulty URL in var options at row 176 in same file `var options = { url: decodeURIComponent(process.env.REQUEST_URL)}`.

This is creating the server error `POST /ixn/activities/dm-activity/execute 500 847ms - 2b`

What kind of URL corresponds to this REQUEST_URL-variable? What URL should i put here? Should I make any changes to REQUEST_URL in app.json? Since i'm using the salesforce github repository as code base I haven't written this code which makes it hard to troubleshoot.

I think the error exist in app.json in root folder where the only attribute is "required: false". Code of app.json below;

```
    {
  "name": "Salesforce JB Custom Activity",
  "description": "Create a Journey Builder Custom Activity for making an http request.",
  "repository": "https://github.com/timsim00/http-request",
  "keywords": ["journey", "builder", "marketing", "cloud", "custom", "activity", "salesforce"],
  "logo": "http://image.s6.exacttarget.com/lib/fe9112727360007b77/m/1/Salesforce_Marketing_Cloud.png",
  "env": {
    "REQUEST_METHOD":{
        "required":false
    },
    "REQUEST_URL":{
        "required":false
    },
    "REQUEST_HEADERS":{
        "required":false
    },
    "REQUEST_BODY":{
        "required":false
    },
    "APP_NAME":"floating-chamber-61254",
    "KEY":"se_hiq_bcf_jb_activity",
    "ACTIVITY_NAME":{
        "required":false
    },
    "ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION":{
        "required":false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the url of the endpoint which is the server the activity is hosted on. This is the value you also added to your app extension in salesforce marketing cloud app center.

More information is given on [github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/http-request: Web Server and App Extension Configuration](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/http-request#web-server)

**Edit:** `REQUEST_URL` is read via `process.env` and therefore is an environment variable that needs to be set on the server running the node.js-application (the endpoint of the activity). This can be done using the following command for running your script: `REQUEST_URL=urlof.your.endppoint node scriptname.js`

Comment: Yes, the endpoint of the execute is already set.But the faulty REQUEST_URL is not in the custom activities config.json, it is in the app.json-file in root folder where the only attribute right now is "required: false". Adding both .json files to extend question background.

Comment: REQUEST_URL is an environment variable which needs to be set on the server running the nodejs application.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, as a temporary solution, I declared the url directly instead of fetching it from the process.env as shown below.

```
var options = { url: "https://myherokuappsname.herokuapp.com/ixn/activities/dm-activity/execute " }
```